# Why do I receive “unrecognized selector sent to instance“ in React Native iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

My code works perfectly on Android but it shows an error in iOS.

**Error in iOS:**

[image: Error on iOS mobile]

I couldn’t understand this error; is it related to `AsyncStorage`?

Why this happening on iOS devices?

---

### First File

**My imports**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import { Alert, Dimensions, Image, TouchableOpacity, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

import { Container, Body, Footer, Header, Input, Item, Left, Text, Title, Right, View, Button, Label, Form} from 'native-base';

import { SimpleLineIcons, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';

import { LinearGradient } from 'expo';

import { StatusBar } from "react-native";

import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-native-easy-grid';

import Toast, {DURATION} from 'react-native-easy-toast';

import Strings from '../utils/Strings';
```

```
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;

export default class Login extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            MobileNo: '',
        };
    }

    login = () => {
        AsyncStorage.setItem('mobileno', MobileNo);

        const { MobileNo } = this.state;
        console.log("Expected login number " + MobileNo);

        fetch('http://demo.weybee.in/Backend/controller/User_Login.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                mobileno: MobileNo
            })
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            // If server response message same as Data Matched
            if(responseJson != 'Enter valid phone number') {   
                const { navigation } = this.props;
                // Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
                this.props.navigation.navigate('ForgetPass');
            } else {
                this.refs.toast.show('Invalid Number', DURATION.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
}
```

### Second File

**My imports**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import { Alert, Dimensions, Image, TouchableOpacity, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

import { Container, Body, Footer, Header, Input, Item, Left, Text, Title, Right, View, Button, Label, Form} from 'native-base';

import { SimpleLineIcons, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';

import { LinearGradient } from 'expo';

import { StatusBar } from "react-native";

import { Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-native-easy-grid';

import Toast, {DURATION} from 'react-native-easy-toast'

import Strings from '../utils/Strings';

import OtpInputs from 'react-native-otp-inputs';
```

```
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width; 

export default class Login extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null
    };

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            MobileNo: '',
            mobileNumber: '',
            code: '',
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('mobileno').then((mobileNo) => {
            if(mobileNo){
                this.setState({ mobileNumber: mobileNo });
            }
        });
    }

    PTP = () => {
        let mobileNumber = JSON.parse(this.state.mobileNumber);
        console.log("login number " + mobileNumber);

        let {code} = this.state;
        console.log(code);

        fetch('http://demo.weybee.in/Backend/controller/Get_PTP.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                mobileno: mobileNumber,
                code: code,
            })
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            // If server response message same as Data Matched
            if(responseJson != 'Enter valid phone number') {     
                const { navigation } = this.props;
                // Then open Profile activity and send user email to profile activity.
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
            } else {
                this.refs.toast.show('Invalid PTP', DURATION.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem might be with how you're saving `MobileNo` to AsyncStorage. Isn't `MobileNo` part of state and shouldn't it be referred to as `this.state.MobileNo`?

Inside FirstFile, This is where the problem is,

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('mobileno', MobileNo);
```

It should be,

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('mobileno', this.state.MobileNo);
```

Comment: I couldn't understand what are you trying to say, can you explore more?

Comment: @AkashThoriya I updated my answer. Try the solution and tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when passing a null value to `AsyncStorage.setItem`:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('user_id', null) // breaks!
```

To fix it, I just passed a string as the value of the setItem command:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('user_id', 'tupac_without_a_nosering') // good!
```